# Using absolute path with os.stat

Tags: python

I would like to iterate through a directories file listing and check the permissions of each file. The following code works well for iterating through each file

```
path = "/home/bob/test"

for i in os.listdir(path):
    osstat = oct(os.stat(i).st_mode & 0777)
```

But the os.stat commands fails as it needs to run against the absolute path.

I know this as if I run the script from /home/bob/test/ it works (as it runs against the working directory)

Should I use:

```
os.chdir(path)
```

Or is there a cleaner way (I don't want to get into changing directories back and forth all the time).

Comment: `os.stat(path+i)` wouldn't work?

Answer (score 2):

Erm...

```
osstat = oct(os.stat(os.path.join(path, i)).st_mode & 0777)
```